# How to display the name of a typed key?

Tags: delphi

I would like to display the name of a pressed Key in a TEdit.

For example, while having focus on TEdit and typing <kbd>A</kbd> would show `A` in the same TEdit. pressing another button such as the <kbd>space</kbd> bar, would show `SPACE`.

I am not sure where to begin, I thought THotKey was an option but I cannot input space which I want to.

EDIT//

After reading some replies, the start was very helpful but I ran into problems that I am not sure how to fix.

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Sender is TEdit then
  case Key of
  chr(65):
    begin
      TEdit(Sender).Text := 'A [65]';
      Key := #0;
    end;
  chr(VK_NUMPAD1):
    begin
      TEdit(Sender).Text := '1';
      Key := #0;
    end;
  chr(32):
    begin
      TEdit(Sender).Text := 'SPACE [32]';
      Key := #0;
    end;
  else
    TEdit(Sender).Text := 'NONE';
  end;
end;
```

65 is upper case A, and without although I don't like it, I can put in 65 and 97 to give same outcome.

VK_NUMPAD1 or any other VK_NUMPAD* does not work, and does not give me error when compiling. I am not sure how to fix this.

I put in an else as I don't want certain characters to be put in, but the outcome is not what I wanted. I was expecting the text to be "NONE" when for example I type z (something I don't want) but it becomes "zNONE". How do I remove the "z" part of "zNONE"

I figured that VK_SPACE and 32 are the same, but cannot figure out how to see NUMPAD.

Thanks. and sorry for the late reply

Comment: Er, if you focus a TEdit and start typing, you do already see the text you typed. I don't quite understand the question. Could you be more precise? Oh, and people would like to see what you already tried. In other words: edit your question and add **your actual code** to it, with copy & paste.

Comment: FWIW, take a look at the OnKeyPress, OnKeyDown and OnKeyUp events. I *guess* you mean something like that.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, the space character should be replaced by the text `SPACE`, for example.

Comment: @LURD, yeah, I figured that much after some re-reading. that is why I added my last comment.

Comment: How about keys like the `back` Should it show the text "back" or should it do what it normal does and remove the last character ?

Comment: You forgot to set `Key := #0;` in the else statement. That would take care of the extra `z` character when pressing the `z` key.

Comment: @LURD yes, that did the trick. Although I am not sure why with this code when I press a it gives me '1' as if the case was NUMPAD1. When I press capital A then it gives me "A [65]". Still haven't figured out how to do NUMPAD keys. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

1. Create a new VCL project.
2. Drop a `TEdit` control on the form and clear its `Text` property.
3. In its `OnKeyPress` event handler, write

   ```
   procedure TForm5.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
   begin
     if Sender is TEdit then
       case Key of
         chr(VK_SPACE):
           begin
             TEdit(Sender).SelText := ' SPACE ';
             Key := #0;
           end;
       end;
   end;
   ```
4. Run the project.

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to study the details of the implementation.

Just a word of caution: the `TEdit(Sender)` typecast is inherently unsafe: if `Sender` isn't a `TEdit` (or something you know is exactly compatible), you have a major bug. That's why this code is beneath the `if Sender is TEdit then` conditional; that makes it perfectly safe.

Comment: Hi, This was very helpful but I ran into problems which I put in as an EDIT. If you can have a look, that would be most helpful. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the `KeyDown` event instead of the `KeyPress` event. You can then there get a text representation of the pressed key using the following code:

```
uses Vcl.Menus;

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyDown(
  Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
    TEdit(Sender).Text := ShortCutToText(ShortCut(Key, Shift));
    Key := 0;
end;

// Disable default behavior in other events
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  Key := #0;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  Key := 0;
end;
```